# appcelerator titanium mobile Facebook login - alway have not set Titanium.Facebook.loggedIn after login

Tags: facebook, authentication, appcelerator

My mobile app will first require user to login facebook and then go back to the app for further action.

After login fb successfully, it is expected that the Titanium.Facebook.loggedIn will be true and the app can get the value in Ti.Facebook.uid.

However, it is not always the case. Sometimes, after login fb successfully and go back to the app, the Titanium.Facebook.loggedIn is still false and sure cannot get the Ti.Facebook.uid.
   But when the user logout and login again within the same app section, it will work fine. Therefore, my app sometimes requires users to login facebook twice.

Do u have any idea of it? The code is listed below.

```
 var login = Titanium.Facebook.createLoginButton({
    top: 100, style:'wide'
});

var actionsView = Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, touchEnabled: false, height: 320
});

var loginView = Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, visible: !Titanium.Facebook.loggedIn, height: Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight,opacity:0.85, backgroundColor:'#fff'
});

loginView.add(login);

Titanium.Facebook.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
       if (Titanium.Facebook.loggedIn){
        loginView.hide();
        actionsView.touchEnabled=true;
       }else{
         statusAlert = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({title:appname,message:'Login failed.'});
         statusAlert.show();
       }

    if (e.error) {
        alert(e.error);
    }
});

var logout = Titanium.Facebook.createLoginButton({
    top: 300, style:'wide', visible: false
});
```

Comment: Is this 1.6 or higher and do you have permissions to ask FB for set?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Titanium.Facebook.uid instead, that would be something like:

```
if (Titanium.Facebook.uid){
```

But probably the problem you are having is due an old Titanium version.

Answer (score 0):

After successful login via facebook save user id into a global variable or in app properties.
I will prefer app properties because unless the user will logout from facebook the uid will remain in the app properties
 i-e

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString('uid', Ti.Facebook.uid);
```

so when you use your app back just check the uid first.

```
var fb_id = Ti.App.Properties.getString('uid');
if(fb_id){
// your code
}
```

and when you logout clear the variable with '' or null.

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit late for an additional answer, but I had a similar problem on iOS. Logging in via FB worked great but after closing the app completely the Facebook module returned 'undefined' when asked for the UID. I solved it by calling the undocumented 'initialize' method.

Follow the setup guide here: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook

And then try this example

```
var fb = require('facebook');

fb.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert('login from uid: ' + e.uid + ', name: ' + JSON.parse(e.data).name);
        showFriends();
    } else if (e.cancelled) {
        // user cancelled
        alert('cancelled');
    } else {
        alert(e.error);
    }
});

fb.initialize();

function authorize(e) {

    fb.authorize();
}

function showFriends() {

    alert("fb:\n" + fb.uid + "\n" + fb.accessToken + "\n" + fb.expirationDate);
    fb.requestWithGraphPath('me/friends', {
        limit : 1000,
    }, 'GET', function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            // Note: only friends who installed this app are returned
            var result = JSON.parse(e.result);

            alert("successfully loaded friends");

            // each data (user) has id + name fields

        } else if (e.error) {
            alert('fb friends: ' + e.error);
        } else {
            alert('Unknown response');
        }
    });
}

if (fb.loggedIn) {
    $.button.hide();
    alert("already logged in");
} else {
    $.button.show();
}

$.index.open();
```

Of course you would need something like

```
<Button id="button" onClick="authorize" >log in</Button>
```

in your view.